# How to decode JSON data from Alamofire request

Tags: json, swift, rest, alamofire, codable

I'm trying to decode the json data after fetching json with alamofire. I have created the model class but i don't understand how to decode the data.

```
Alamofire.request("http://somerandomlink.xyz").responseJSON { (response) in
            switch response.result {
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            case .success(let data):
                do {
                    //print(response)
                    print("data: \(data)")
                } catch let error {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }
```

Model

```
struct LoremIpsum: Codable {
   let var1: String
   let var2: String
   let var3: String
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alamofire has been updated to use `Codable` objects natively.

Use:

```
.responseDecodable(of: LoremIpsum.self) {
```

Instead of:

```
.responseJSON {
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use .responseData instead of responseJSON and then in the success case you can try decoding using JSONDecoder as follows:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
do {
     let users = try decoder.decode(LoremIpsum.self, from:data)
     print("Users list :", users)
    } catch {
     print(error)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        guard let users = try? JSONDecoder().decode(LoremIpsum.self, from: response) else {
            return
        }
```